# Offline installation of addtional drivers , how to determine correct pakage

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does 12.04 need graphics drivers for NVidia?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125687/does-12-04-need-graphics-drivers-for-nvidia)

I have an old system  which is not connected to internet. The computer specification as below,

- Intel Dual Core
- 3GB RAM
- Mobo : [Asus P5N73- AM](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5N73AM/#specifications)

Now if you see the specification of mobo, you can see the chipset is `NVIDIA GeForce 7050/nForce 610i` and VGA card is `Integrated GeForce 7050 GPU`.

I used to run ubuntu 11.10 on that system and install drivers from `Addtional drivers`.

Now gave the desktop to my sister, and installed ubuntu 12.04 from a image created by remastersys.

I removed all unnecessary softwares, drivers after installation. It is now working fine.Unity 3D is running but very slow. So I think I need to install the additional driver.

As I told earlier, it is not connected to Internet. Only thing I can do to  download the package from another system and install it there. But I couldn't determine which package needs to be downloaded.

Comment: I got the answers from here http://askubuntu.com/q/125687/35775

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graphics card is not supported with the latest version of the Nvidia drivers, you need to install [the legacy drivers called `nvidia-173`](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-173.14.31-driver.html) from the *restricted* repository.

To get a list of packages and dependencies necessary to install the drivers you can use this command to get that list saved to a `.txt`file ([`source`](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/11/get-list-of-packages-and-dependencies.html)), don't worry, it will not install naything in your system:

```
sudo apt-get --print-uris --yes --reinstall install nvidia-173 | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 > nvidia-173.txt
```

After you have the list and checked the `.txt` file you can then download the packages with `wget` or any other downloader tool of your choice:

```
wget --input-file nvidia-173.txt
```

this will read each line in the `nvidia-173.txt` file and download it to you current directory.

After you saved the files in a USB drive or any other removable media you can then just go to your other computer, change directory to where you saved the files and use `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to install them.

Comment: receiving this error - `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Use `sudo apt-get --print-uris --yes --reinstall install nvidia-173` in a terminal and check for errors, post them if you find anything relevant.

Comment: Getting this message `nvidia-173 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-10 but it is not installable` . i tried in one virtual machine also. Same error. However I will try with the package in nvidia site. Will let you know.

Comment: @Web-E :/ I have been checking and seems like the package is broken for 12.04. I will update this asap.

Comment: I have an even older graphics chipset (NForce4) and as far as I can work out, I need the nvidia-96 package.  When I use the above commands but modified for nvidia-96, I get the same errors so fingers crossed, once the package is fixed, it may well work for me too!

Comment: I have heard the fix is released (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-173/+bug/948053) but still I am having problem. So I installed the `nvidia-current` from `x org-updates` ppa and its working fine. Not much lag like before. @BrunoPereira Please close this question.